# SQL - UPDATE (Using existing rows in same table)

Tags: sql, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table (see below:  Current Table) in which I need to `UPDATE` Row# 5 because a value for ID1 already exist (Row# 4) and a value for `ID3` already exist (Row# 3).  There are three (3) use cases on which to `UPDATE` the table.

Additional context:  In the final state, `ID1` will have one and only one `ID2`, but can have many `ID3`.  `ID3` can have many `ID1` and `ID2`.  `ID1` and `ID3` are unique values, iff `ID1` OR `ID3` does not exist in table, then `ID2` is assigned the value of `ID1`.

Use cases for `UPDATE`

1. An existing row (smaller row # and `TIME` value) has the same `ID1`
   value.  Use the `ID2` value for that existing `ID1` value.
2. An existing row (smaller row # and `TIME` value) has the same `ID3` value.  Use the `ID2` value for that existing `ID3` value.
3. Both `ID1` and `ID3` values exist (Not the same rows though).  Use the `ID2` value from the row with the smallest (oldest) `TIME` value.

Current Table

```
Row    ID1    ID2    ID3    TIME  
1      A      A      123    12:01AM  
2      A      A      456    12:05AM  
3      A      A      789    12:10AM  
4      B      A      123    12:15AM  
5      B      B      789    12:20AM  
6      C      C      987    12:25AM
```

Updated Table

```
Row    ID1    ID2    ID3    TIME  
1      A      A      123    12:01AM  
2      A      A      456    12:05AM  
3      A      A      789    12:10AM  
4      B      A      123    12:15AM  
5      B      A      789    12:20AM  
6      C      C      987    12:25AM
```

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am working with Snowflake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your conditions simplify to getting the earliest `id2` from a matching `id1` or `id3`:

```
update t
    set id2 = tt.new_id
    from (select t.*,
                 (select t2.id2
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id1 = t.id1 or t2.id3 = t.id3
                 ) as new_id
          from t
         ) tt
    where t.id1 = tt.id1;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I assume on the last line `where t.id = tt.id` should be `t.id1 = tt.id1` ?

Comment: Also, in the nested `where t2.id1 = t.id1 or t2.id3 = t2.id3` should be `where t2.id1 = t.id1 or t2.id3 = t.id3` ?

Comment: The solution you provided works with the example given in my request.  When running the code on bigger examples, it is updating all rows in the table but not changing `ID2`.  Can you explain how the solution you wrote is getting the "earliest"?